# Android OS language lookup: let OS know what the app's default language is

Tags: android, locale, lookup

My `values/strings.xml` is written in locale `nl-NL`. I also have a `values/nl-rBE/strings.xml` file present. For device language `nl-NL`, the OS chooses to use `nl-BE` strings and that is not what I want.

Is there a way to let the Android OS know what my default `values/strings.xml` locale is, without duplicating the file to `values/nl-NL/strings.xml`?

**So currently:**
Device language `nl-NL` => `values-nl-rBE/strings.xml`

**I want:**
Device language `nl-NL` = `values/strings.xml`

Comment: if the values in nl-NL are what you consider your default values then why not just copy what is in there and put them in your `values/string.xml` (which is what the OS defaults to) then delete your nl-NL string.xml file?

Comment: that's the problem. the OS does not take values/strings.xml but is 'smarter' and takes the nl-BE strings instead. I want it to take values/strings.xml